# Como ler página por página de um PDF com PDFBox

Tags: java

Boa Tarde.

Gostaria de saber se alguém consegue me ajudar. Preciso extrair dados de um arquivo em PDF, porém preciso ler página por página do arquivo, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
    PDDocument pdDoc = null;
    COSDocument cosDoc = null;
    File file = new File("C\\testes\\teste.pdf");
    try {
        PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file)); //Aqui o FileInputStream está acusando erro;
        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
        pdfStripper.setEndPage(5);
        String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        System.out.println(parsedText);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim funciona?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class SuaClasse {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File file = new File("C\\testes\\teste.pdf");
        try {
            PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(file));
            parser.parse();
            COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                pdfStripper.setStartPage(i);
                pdfStripper.setEndPage(i);
                String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
                System.out.println("Página " + i + ": " + parsedText);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Tratar a exceção adequadamente.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema é que ali no "FileInputStream" ele fica acusando um erro que não sei o motivo. Ele pede pra adicionar a importação java.io.FileInputStream, só que quando adiciono ele diz para converter o FileInputStream para RandomAcessRead, porém se eu faço essa conversão ele acusa erro justamente nessa conversão

Comment: @R.Santos Atualizei a resposta. E agora?

Comment: ele trouxe as informações do pdf sim, obrigado. Porém ele trouxe com uma mensagem de erro entre cada pagina "jun 23, 2016 5:54:43 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont toUnicode
ADVERTÊNCIA: No Unicode mapping for .notdef (9) in font Times-Bold", tu saberia dizer o que seria?

Comment: Mais uma pergunta, os pdfs vão ter diferentes tamanhos, e precisaria as informações de todas as paginas, tens como me ajudar com isso? Obrigado pela ajuda até agora;

Comment: @R.Santos Quanto a essa advertência, isso é porque ele encontrou algum símbolo unicode que ele não sabe o que é. Não sei como resolver isso, mas a menos que algo muito errado ocorra, deve ser seguro ignorar esse problema por enquanto. Quanto ao número de páginas, atualizei a minha resposta.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pela ajuda mesmo

Comment: Cara estou dando continuidade neste mesmo código, pois preciso pegar determinadas informações destas páginas de PDF, para isso estou usando matcher e pattern. Tu saberia me dizer como faço para ler linha a linha de cada página do PDF? Grato

Comment: @R.Santos Não, não saberia. Ao menos não ainda. Recomendo que poste uma nova questão acerca disso, e coloque nela um link para esta questão aqui.

Comment: Obrigado. Se conseguir alguma coisa posto aqui